# Prove that $P(A \cap B) = 1 - P(A^c) - P(B^c) + P(A^c \cap B^c)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing

I'm having trouble seeing or proving how $P(A \cap B)$ equals that. I know $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ for independent events, but no idea on this case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

$$A^C\cap B^C = (A\cup B)^C$$

$$P(X) = 1- P(X^C)$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Following it, I arrive at P(A n B) = P(A) + P(B) + P(A u B)^c - 1. Does my next step involve rewriting P(A u B)^c or breaking it down?

Comment: $P((A\cup B)^C) = 1-P(A\cup B)$

Answer (score 0):

Note: $$P(A^C)=1-P(A),$$ $$P(B^C)=1-P(B),$$ $$P(A^C \cap B^C)=1-P(A\cup B).$$
Hence:
$$P(A \cap B) = 1 - (1-P(A)) - (1-P(B)) + (1-P(A\cup B) \iff$$
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$P(A \cap B) = 1-P((A \cap B)^C) = 1-P(A^C \cup B^C) =$$

$$ 1-(P(A^C) +P(B^C)-P(A^C \cap B^C)=1-P(A^C) -P(B^C) +P(A^C \cap B^C)$$